El jar final de maven no encuentra las dependencias locales ¿Que hago?
Hola soy un estudiante de POO y estoy intentando hacerle package a mi proyecto pero en el utilizo dependencias propias mias que al momento de crear el .jar final no se pueden usar por alguna razón, el JVM lanza una excepción diciendo que no las encuentra a pesar de que en VSC el código funciona perfectamente.
El jar se crea sin probleamas pero al intentar correrlo en terminal con java -jar es cuando aparece el problema y es que no corre.
Estoy trabajando con el openJDK 17.0.10 en VSC y con Maven 3.8.7 por si sirve de algo.
Les comparto mi pom.xml por si pueden ayudarme a solucionarlo perdon que sea un desorden en este momento pero estuve probando muchas cosas.
`
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>edu.upvictoria.fpoo</groupId>
<artifactId>practica-1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>local-maven-repo</id>
    <url>file:///${project.parent.basedir}/libs</url>
</repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>archivo</groupId>
    <artifactId>archivo</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/archivo-1.3.1.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>Input</groupId>
    <artifactId>Input</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/Input-1.3.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>edu.upvictoria.fpoo.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    <mainClass>edu.upvictoria.fpoo.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

`
